# Writing to a new Xml file using Python Error Message?

Tags: python, cgi

What is this error message ?

My code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from xml.dom.minidom import Document

def CreateXml(nameSpace, rootElementName):
    xmlDoc = xml.dom.minidom.Document()
    xmlRootElement = doc.createElementNS(nameSpace, rootElementName)
    xmlDoc.appendChild(xmlRootElement)

    return xmlDoc
```

Error is

```
File "/home/users/web/b2896/moo.something/cgi-bin/py/sbmain/main.py", line 27, in initialize 
xmlDoc = py.sbxml.XmlDocumentHandler.CreateXml(_GUESTNAMESPACE, 'guest') 
File "/home/users/web/b2896/moo.something/cgi-bin/py/sbxml/XmlDocumentHandler.py", line 6, in CreateXml 
xmlDoc = xml.dom.minidom.Document() 
NameError: global name 'xml
```

Is it because it is not able to able to find the path of my python?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please paste the full error next time.

Comment: Also paste a complete test file, imports are important, you can use pasteboard or something similar if you want.

Comment: That's not really necessary for that kind of error

Comment: @ThiefMaster - No i have it, Sorry i editted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to `import xml.dom.minidom` to import the *XML minidom* module.

```
>>> xml.dom.minidom.Document()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'xml' is not defined
>>> import xml.dom.minidom
>>> xml.dom.minidom.Document()
<xml.dom.minidom.Document instance at 0x7f73ae601a28>
```